# Contabo's Object Storage - Object Lock Retention (AWS S3 compatible)

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm having difficulty with [Contabo's Object Storage](https://contabo.com/en/object-storage/).

With a user with permission: "S3 Object Storage Read and Write" I configured a aws profile called 'backup'.

With this profile, I ran this shell script:

```
echo "Bucket: "$BUCKET
echo "Key: "$KEY
echo "Profile: "$PROFILE
echo "Region: "$REGION
echo "Endpoint: "$ENDPOINT

aws --profile $PROFILE --region $REGION --endpoint-url $ENDPOINT \
   s3api get-object-retention --bucket $BUCKET --key $KEY
```

And then, I got this result:

```
Bucket: test1
Key: test_one.txt
Profile: backup
Region: default
Endpoint: https://usc1.contabostorage.com
{
    "Retention": {
        "Mode": "COMPLIANCE",
        "RetainUntilDate": "2023-05-06T17:35:57.568865+00:00"
    }
}
```

This means that even the root user could delete this file before: "2023-05-06T17:35:57.568865+00:00" right?

After this, I ran this shell script:

```
echo "Bucket: "$BUCKET
echo "Key: "$KEY
echo "Profile: "$PROFILE
echo "Region: "$REGION
echo "Endpoint: "$ENDPOINT

aws --profile $PROFILE --region $REGION --endpoint-url $ENDPOINT \
     s3 rm s3://$BUCKET/$KEY
```

And then, I got this result:

```
Bucket: test1
Key: test_one.txt
Profile: backup
Region: default
Endpoint: https://usc1.contabostorage.com
delete: s3://test1/test_one.txt
```

So the file was deleted. The retention mode is "COMPLIANCE" and the file was deleted. Why?